# angularjs: Push is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON object like this:

```
var post = {
    "post_id": "1",
    "content": "content",
    "post_author": {
        "id": "12",
        "firstName": "Amelia",
        "lastName": "Earheart",
    },
    "isLiked": false,
    "likes_count": 0,
    "likers": [],
    "comments_count": 0,
    "commenters": [],
    "comments": []
};
```

And `post` is passed to the function given below from the front end.

```
var vm = this;
vm.likePost = function(post) {
    var likedPost = post;
    vm.userInfo();
    likedPost.likers.push(userObject); //Here

    myService.postLike(likedPost).success(function(data) {
        likedPost.isLiked = true;
        likedPost.likes_count++;
        vm.posts = data;
    });
};
```

But doing so, I get a JavaScript error saying `push is not a function` in line `likedPost.likers.push(userObject);`

And `userObject` is returned by `vm.userInfo()` and it looks like this:

```
vm.userInfo = function() {
    myService.getBasicUserInfo().success(function(data) {
        vm.currentPost.post_author.id = data.id;
        vm.currentPost.post_author.firstName = data.firstName;
        vm.currentPost.post_author.lastName = data.lastName;
    });
};
```

and the returned JSON is like this:

```
{"id":"12","firstName":"Amelia","lastName":"Earheart"}
```

Can anyone help me figure out the cause of this issue?

UPDATE:

```
{
    "post_id": "12",
    "content": "Content is the content that contains the content",
    "image": "member-default.jpg",
    "created_at": "2016-05-26 14:29:00",
    "post_author": {
        "id": "12",
        "firstName": "Amelia",
        "lastName": "Earheart",
    },
    "isLiked": false,
}
```

This is what I get upon `console.log(likedPost);`

Comment: Before the push call can you add this : 
console.log(likedPost);
and send the result

Comment: OK. Give me a minute. @Silvinus

Comment: This error means that `likers` is not an array

Comment: What is the source of your JSON object? Maybe there is an error in constructing it, or in receiving it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output clearly specifies that `likers` is not defined. You can put a validation check before using `push()` method.

```
//if likedPost.likers is not defined, it will define it as an array 
likedPost.likers = likedPost.likers || [];

//Do the push operation
likedPost.likers.push(userObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `likedPost` object doesn't have the `likers` array you expect. Probably you can see if that exists before trying to push.

```
if (typeof likedPost !== 'undefined')
   likedPost.likers.push(userObject);
```

Comment: You could simply put (if likedPost) because it would return false if null or undefined

Comment: all the reason why IE needs to die a quick and horrifyingly painful death